# How to center align an ICON inside a BUTTON in materialize css navbar?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I read many post on SO about how to center align an ICON inside a BUTTON, but none of them work for my case, since in my case the BUTTON is inside a navbar.

Please see the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avocado123321/ovuydgm9/1/), also pasted in the code block below.

```html
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


        <div class="navbar-fixed">
          <nav class="teal">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="nav-wrapper">
                <a href="#" class="brand-logo">LOGO </a>
                <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                  <li>
                    <form class="orange" style="">
                      <div style="display: inline-flex; border: 1px black solid; align-items: center;">
                        <input id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="text text..." style="border: 1px red solid; margin: 0; height: 100%;">
                        <button class="btn" type="submit" style="background: blue; height:45px;">
                          <i class="material-icons" style="border: 1px red solid; display: inline; margin: auto;">search</i>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#home">Home</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
```

The issue is that, the search ICON is not vertically centered inside BUTTON, and I tried many suggested methods, none worked.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: @avacado check my answer, check if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to add `line-height: 45px` to your `icon` , scince you added the `height:45px;` to your button , just like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="teal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">LOGO </a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li>
            <form class="orange" style="">
              <div style="display: inline-flex; border: 1px black solid; align-items: center;">
                <input id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="text text..." style="border: 1px red solid; margin: 0; height: 100%;">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" style="background: blue; height:45px;">
                  <i class="material-icons" style="border: 1px red solid; display: inline; margin: auto;line-height:45px;">search</i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed it works! I didn't know about this `line-height` property before, so briefly why we need this in my case?

Comment: it gives the heith of the parent's element of your icon to itself , so it can center it self in it , usely we use it onlu for icons in the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

if your navbar has fixed height this CSS is enough for you https://jsfiddle.net/fw9cmaq6/

```
.material-icons{
 margin-top:-8px;
}
```

if not fixed height just use this

```
.material-icons{
  display: table-cell !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height:0 !important;
  height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks it works, but could please explain why this could work? I try to learn what's going on behind the scene.

Comment: it work because u have fixed height  and with margin u change its position as 8px to top. margin is used to change position.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Then this solution is not quite generalizable, if the height has changed.

Comment: This answer would be better with all of the pertinent code here on Stack Overflow. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make a runnable example.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adjusting the margin for the search div in your code. Hope this helps. I have fixed it in your code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="teal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">LOGO </a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li>
            <form class="orange" style="">
              <div style="display: inline-flex; border: 1px black solid; align-items: center;">
                <input id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="text text..." style="border: 1px red solid; margin: 0; height: 100%;">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" style="background: blue; height:45px;">
                  <div style="margin-top: -9px;">  
                  <i class="material-icons" style="border: 1px red solid; display: inline; ">search</i>
                  </div>  
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this(View in full screen)

```css
#container {
  height: 65px;
  display: flex;
}

#search-bar {
  height: 100%;
}

button.btn {
  height: auto !important;
}

.material-icons {
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="teal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">LOGO </a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li>
            <form class="orange">
              <div id="container">
                <input id="search-bar" type="search" placeholder="text text...">
                <button class="btn" type="submit" style="background: blue; height:45px;">
                          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                        </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```